# How do you find the beehive?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I need help on finding the bee hive. I want to defeat queen bee so I can get the witch doctor but I don't know where to look. Is going deep underground and finding yellow water mean you are near a beehive? Because I was digging and found yellow water. Is there a certain depth you have to be at to get to the beehive?

Comment: Yellow water = honey?

Answer (score 4):

The beehive can be found at any depth in the **Underground Jungle** biome.

There are several Bee Hive's per world depending on how large the world is.